# Block does not move using keyframes

Tags: css, animation

The keyframes aren't making the block move. I'm new to using keyframes so I'm bad at it.

```
#block{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    top: 130px;
    left: 480px;
    animation: block is infinite linear;
}

@keyframes block{
    0%{left:480px;}
    100%{left: -40px;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your code using the examples on [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations). I hope this is the expected behavior.

`animation-iteration-count: infinite;` will make the animation repeat forever.

`animation-name` defines the identifier used in @keyframes.

`animation-duration` specifies how many seconds or milliseconds the animation takes to complete.

See also https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation.asp.

```css
#block{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 130px;
    left: 480px;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-name: block;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes block  {
    0% {
      left: 480px; 
    }
    
    100% {
      left: -40px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="block"></div>
```

Comment: @cheems-bread I have updated my answer and include another helpful link.